# Running external executable file from Java program

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to write a Java program which gets a executable file to run under Linux. This executable file receives two parameters and performs a **nmap -sP** operating with the two given parameters.

I've called this file as *file.exe* and its content is the one below:

> **`nmap -sP $segment1-$segment1`**

I already did a **`chmod +x file.exe`** and  it's in same directory where the *`.class`*  is present.

The Java code is the following:

```
import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.lang.Process;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;

    public class runFile {

        public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec("file.exe "+args[0]+" "+args[1]);
            p.waitFor();
        }


    }
```

After compiling, Whenever I try to run it (from where the file.exe is) by

> **`java runFile`**

I'm getting the following exception and errors log:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "file.exe": error=2, No such file or directory    at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)  at
>   runFile.main(runFile.java:12) Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2,
>   No such file or directory     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:135)   at
>   java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)     at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)  ... 4 more

***What am I missing?***

Comment: Have you tried to specify the absolute path to file.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that the executable can not be found in the current directory or the OS's search path.

Try including the Pathans part of the command

```
Process p = r.exec("/path/to/file.exe "+args[0]+" "+args[1]);
```

You should also consider separating each command/argument as a separate parameter

```
Process p = r.exec(new String[]{"/path/to/file.exe ", args[0], args[1]});
```

This will help with parameters that contain spaces.

You should also consider using `ProcessBuilder`, this will allow you to change the directory context that the command should be executed

Comment: It's telling me that `exec` has not a suitable `exec(String, String, String)` method.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking of ProcessBuilder, need to use String array

Answer (score 0):

Your java program looks for `file.exe` in the directory where you started your java program. It does not look inside the directory with your class files.